# Zend Framework 2: route to another controller when requested does not exist

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework2

For example, I have controllers: `showpage` and `admin`.
Url: `domain.com/admin` for this, my controller runs OK.
For `domain.com/showpage/page/about` routing run a function `pageAction()` in `showpage` controller - it's ok.

But how I can do it when any URL requested:

1. Check is controller exist and run it
2. If not, try use `pageAction()` from `showpage` controller
3. If page isn't exist, redirect to 404

I want for URL `domain.com/example` run `domain.com/showpage/page/example` (if controller `example` don't exist)

How I can do it?

Function `pageAction()` check is requested page exists and show it - from .txt files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can use your `ErrorController` for this. If the controller or action name is not found then you will get the error 500 and you will be routed to your `ErrorController`. You can then redirect people to wherever you want them to go